# lightning out "runtime_appointmentbooking:lightningOutGuest" does not work

Tags: lightning-out, lightning-scheduler

I have been trying to embed Salesforce Scheduler flow to my external website.
When I deploy the following code, `bootstrap.js` and `inline.js` returns 404 error. (Let's say `https://xxx.my.site.com/` is experience cloud site URL)
So the flow is not showing up.
An external site URL is added on CORS.
How can I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <div id='lexcontainer'>
        <p>flow here</p>
      </div>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="https://xxx.my.site.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
      <script>
        $Lightning.use("runtime_appointmentbooking:lightningOutGuest",
            function() {                  // Callback once framework and app load
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "lightning:flow",    // top-level component of your app
                    { },    // attributes to set on the component when created
                    "lexcontainer",    // the DOM location to insert the component
                    function(component) {            // API name of the Flow
                        component.startFlow("Guest_New_Appointment");
                    }
                );
            },    'https://xxx.my.site.com/'  // Site endpoint
        );
    </script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: try to use another browser like edge, there is probably some setting or plugin on chrome that conflicts